# cordova run with ios error .. Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args:

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, cordova-plugins

This **error occur only** when I try to `cordova run ios --device`

Even after `cordova build ios` command executed, non error is reported.

Whats I do wrong? And how to debug cordova projects on my iPhone (need this because need to test a Camera feature)

```
WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies
Code Sign error: No provisioning profiles found: No non–expired provisioning profiles were found.

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        Check dependencies
(1 failure)
Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/ridermansb/Projects/jdapp/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,CorrijaMe.xcodeproj,ARCHS=armv7 armv7s arm64,-target,CorrijaMe,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphoneos,build,VALID_ARCHS=armv7 armv7s arm64,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/ridermansb/Projects/jdapp/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/ridermansb/Projects/jdapp/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: /Users/ridermansb/Projects/jdapp/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

Comment: Here is the solution guys !!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36095819/cordova-ios-error-building-images-xcassets/36968113#36968113

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You need a development provisioning profile on your build machine. Apps can run on the simulator without a profile, but they are required to run on an actual device.

If you open the project in Xcode, it may automatically set up provisioning for you. Otherwise you will have to create go to the iOS Dev Center and create a profile.

Answer (score 50):

Try to remove and add ios again

```
ionic cordova platform remove ios

ionic cordova platform add ios
```

Worked in my case

Comment: With Ionic 2 it is "ionic cordova platform {add|remove} ios"

Answer (score 25):

I had the same problem. In my case `cordova platform update ios` helped. The reason was in outdated version.

Comment: Thanks Khrystyna Skvarok! This helped when adding and removing the platform alone didn't work. It seems the ios version is not explicitly updated when you run `platform remove ios` and `platform add ios`

Comment: `cordova platform update android||ios` is no longer supported. You need to do `cordova platform remove android||ios` then  `cordova platform add android||ios`

Answer (score 25):

I was getting the same error when I tried to do :

`cordova build ios`

except mine said ** ARCHIVE FAILED ** rather than  ** BUILD FAILED **.

I fixed it by opening the *projectName*.xcodeproj file in Xcode and then adjusting these 2 settings :

1. In *Targets > General > Signing* ensure you have selected a Team

[image]

2. In *Targets > Build Settings > (search for "bitcode")* set Enable Bitcode to "Yes"

[image]

Then I quit out of Xcode and reran `cordova build ios` and it worked.

Comment: Note that I then needed to change the Enable Bitcode setting back to "No" to get it to run from Xcode, but I still think that step was necessary to fix the cordova build issue.

Comment: All I had to do was open it in XCode and set up provisioning profile. Didn't need to enable bitcode.

Comment: Future visitors: `Archive failed` means there is a signature related problem i.e. no provisioning profile. Open Xcode and select a team and Xcode will generate/find a provisioning profile for you.

Answer (score 10):

Open xCode can be exhausting if you do it everytime, so you need to add this flag :

- cordova build ios --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"

OR if you have build.json file at the root of your project, you must add this lines:

```
 {
  "ios": {
    "debug": {
      "buildFlag": [
        "-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
      ]
    },
    "release": {
      "buildFlag": [
        "-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this will help in the future

Answer (score 5):

I tried a few things in this scenario.

I removed ios and installed many times. Went down the path of deleting Splash screens to no avail! Bitcode on/off so many times.

However, after selecting a iOS provisioning team, and running `pod update` inside `./platforms/ios`, I am pleased to announce this resolved my problems.

Hopefully you can try the same and get some resolution?

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was the app icon PNG file... I mean, it took 1 day to go from the provided error

> Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args:

to the human-readable one:

> "the PNG file icon is no good for the picky Apple Xcode"

Comment: Any hint on how to move from the cryptic cordova error to a more closer to the reality one? Any tutorial or guide?

Answer (score 2):

I must add :

I had the same problem, it was coming from the fact that my teammate had a different version of cordova, and commited plugins on the repo with his version.

For all cordova plugins, I had to :

```
cordova plugin rm <plugin-name> 
cordova plugin add <plugin-name>
```

And ask my teammate to update his cordova to match my version

Answer (score 2):

1) Open code in Xcode
2) Continue with : `ionic cordova build ios`

Answer (score 2):

Same problem for me today, with "ARCHIVE FAILED". None of the solutions above worked for me, but watching closer, the error refers the path of module cordova-plugin-inappbrowser, so i removed the  plugin, then added it again, and it finally works...

```
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

stack :

```
Ionic cli 6.2.2
Ionic1 1.3.2
Cordova cli 9.0.0
Cordova platform ios 5.1.1
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.2.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Error code 65 can also show up, if you have something (like your device) plugged into the computer, while building.

Answer (score 1):

How to do what @connor said:

iOS

- Open `platforms/ios` on XCode
- Find & Replace `io.ionic.starter` in all files for a unique identifier
- Click the project to open settings
- Signing > Select a team
- Go to your device Settings > General > DeviceManagement

  - Trust your account/team
- `ionic cordova run ios --device --livereload`

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview` so did the below which worked for me after trying anything else:

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
```

Found it on xCode after trying to rebuild failed build from:

```
ionic cordova build ios
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what helped me

STEP 1 (build.xcconfig)

```
// xcode 13
EXCLUDED_ARCHS__EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_SUFFIX_simulator__NATIVE_ARCH_64_BIT_x86_64=arm64 arm64e armv7 armv7s armv6 armv8
EXCLUDED_ARCHS=$(inherited)
$(EXCLUDED_ARCHS__EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_SUFFIX_$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_SUFFIX)__NATIVE_ARCH_64_BIT_$(NATIVE_ARCH_64_BIT))

IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 12.0
```

STEP 2 (Podfile)

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
      config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'arm64'
      config.build_settings['CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER'] ='NO'
      config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'YES'
    end
  end
end

IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 12.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to change the app icon and you get this error then you should have a picture with larger dimensions like 180x180.