# cordova ios build error 65, but working fine from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I'm getting following error while ios build from Cordova.
But everything is working fine in XCODE.
Note: I'm using 2 dev account because 1 of our app in live. So there are 2 accounts in same mac machine. I hope this doesn't matter with this issue.

I'm sharing the error and the certificate screen shot from XCode

Error Message:

[image]

And the certificates screen shot from Xcode (which is all working fine).

[image]

Anybody having any clue about will help us a lot, THANKS.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34166175/cordova-run-with-ios-error-error-code-65-for-command-xcodebuild-with-args

Comment: No, actually I'm getting error when I'm liking the Team Provisioning in XCODE. If I won't link it, it works well from CLI. But once linked from XCODE it fails with same error code.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because I have project has pre-installed plugins. These plugins was request additional variables (like facebook4 plugin). If you have any plugins request variables first remove it:

`ionic cordova rm plugin cordova-plugin-facebook`

Then remove your platform and add it again

`ionic cordova platform rm ios`

`ionic cordova platform add ios`

*Because you don't have any problems with your plugins, your platform will be added in correct way*

Then `ionic cordova build ios`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this flag :

- cordova build ios --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"

OR if you have build.json file at the root of your project, you must add this lines:

```
 {
  "ios": {
    "debug": {
      "buildFlag": [
        "-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
      ]
    },
    "release": {
      "buildFlag": [
        "-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this will help in the future