# ionic build ios --release build fails results in Error code 65

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, ionic2, release

`ionic build ios`works fine but I went to do `ionic build ios --release` and the first time it didn't fail but it didn't build succeed either.

The second time I tried I got this error?

```
The following build commands failed:

Ld build/My\ App.build/Release-iphonesimulator/My\ 
App.build/Objects-normal/i386/My\ App normal i386
(1 failure)

Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -
xcconfig,/Users/me/desktop/app/platforms/ios/cordova/
build-release.xcconfig,-project,My App.xcodeproj,-target,My App,-
configuration,Release,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS 
Simulator,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/me/desktop/
 app/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/me/
desktop/app/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
```

I've done ionic build ios and uploaded it to testflight and itunes connect through xcode in the past without issue in order to test.

Is that way still ok for the final production version to submit to the store or must it be the release command?

I was just about to get the app on the store so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you try with xCode ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34166175/cordova-run-with-ios-error-error-code-65-for-command-xcodebuild-with-args

Comment: Thanks, I've ionic build ios and then submitted it to itunes connect through xcode in the past without issue. But ionic said to do ionic build ios --release for the production ready one? https://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html

Comment: try `ionic build ios --prod --release`

Comment: If you don't mind can you please explain: (when putting builds for testflight I just needed ionic build ios and then validated and archived in xcode to get it up.) So why for the production/app submit ready one it needs to have the release or prod --release command as well, what does that command do or that makes it different for the prod version? Thanks!

Comment: there is a discussion regarding that https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-build-production-apps-today/73219/8

Comment: Let me know if it works..can add answer and close this :)

Comment: Just doing --prod did it, thanks @suraj!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `--prod` option when you are building Ionic 2 project for production.

```
ionic build ios --prod --release
```

Check discussion [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-build-production-apps-today/73219/6)