# Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild How solve it?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, build

I run ionic cordova build ios and the response ever is a error

Please help me

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileXIB MyApp/Classes/MainViewController.xib
(1 failure)
CordovaError: Promise rejected with non-error: 'Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/linuxplus/Public/Teste/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,MyApp.xcworkspace,-scheme,MyApp,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone SE,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/linuxplus/Public/Teste/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/linuxplus/Public/Teste/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch'
    at cli.catch.err (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova:30:15)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova build ios exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Comment: Hope this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34166175/cordova-run-with-ios-error-error-code-65-for-command-xcodebuild-with-args

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This must be appearing in Xcode 10.x, I believe. In that case, it is because the build system has been changed in Xcode 10.x.

Try using below command:

- Build: `ionic cordova build ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"`
- Run: `ionic cordova run ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0" --livereload`

Reference: https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/407#issue-360392411

Hope this helps.

Comment: Xcode 8.2.1 and macOS sierra 10.12

I try thats flags but don't work

Comment: Which command you are running for this ? Check this: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/1197#issuecomment-234578084

Comment: ionic cordova build ios --prod

Comment: My ionic info

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.8.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.1

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.3.2, (and 4 other plugins)

System:

   ios-sim : 7.0.0
   NodeJS  : v10.15.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm     : 6.4.1
   OS      : macOS Sierra
   Xcode   : Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ionic cordova build ios --prod --verbose -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
```