# xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65 (Cordova)

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, xcodebuild, html-framework-7

I created an app based on Framework7 using cordova

But when compiling, an error occurs after the command

```
sudo cordova build ios
```

Error:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileStoryboard /Users/andreybal/ios_app/quiktrakpro1/platforms/ios/QuikTrak+\ Pro/CDVLaunchScreen.storyboard (in target 'QuikTrak+ Pro' from project 'QuikTrak+ Pro')
(1 failure)
xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65
```

Please tell me what could be the reason

```
cordova -v
11.0.0
```

macOS Monterey

my config.xml :

> android-versionCode="66"   ios-CFBundleVersion="29"
> id="com.quiktrak.pro"   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
> xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0"
> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> defaultlocale="en-US" >   
> QuikTrak+ Pro
>
> QuikTrak Pro GPS tracker
>
>
> Sinopacific Co Limited
>
> ```
> <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
> <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
> <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
> <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
> <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
> <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
> <platform name="android">
>     <allow-intent href="market:*" />
> </platform>
> <platform name="ios">
>     <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
>     <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
> </platform>
> <platform name="android">
>     <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
>         <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
>     </edit-config>    </platform>
> <platform name="ios">
>     <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
>     <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
>         <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
>     </feature>
>     <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
>     <edit-config target="ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
>       <false/>
>     </edit-config>   
> </platform>
> ```
>
> ```
>  <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="30" />
>  <preference name="multiDexEnabled" value="true" />
>  <preference name="deployment-target" value="11" />
>  <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
>  <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="blacktranslucent" />
>  <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-9.0.0" />
>  <!-- <preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" /> -->
>
> <!-- <platform name="ios">
>     <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
>
>     <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
>         <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
>     </feature>
>
>     <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
> </platform> -->
>
>    
> <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" source="npm" spec="2.3.0">
>     <variable name="SENDER_ID" value="1097482483564" />
> </plugin>
> <platform name="android">
>   <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="app/google-services.json" />
> </platform>
> <platform name="ios">
>   <resource-file src="GoogleService-Info.plist" />
> </platform>
>
>
> <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" spec="2.1.3" />
> <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" spec="2.0.3" />
> <plugin name="cordova-plugin-buildinfo" source="npm" spec="4.0.0" />    
> <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm" spec="1.2.1" />
> <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="1.2.1" />
> <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" spec="5.0.2" />
> <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" source="npm" spec="4.0.3"  />   
> <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-mobile-accessibility" source="npm" spec="~1.0.5"  />
> <plugin name="cordova-launch-review" source="npm" spec="3.1.1" />
> <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" spec="4.0.0"  />
> <plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine" spec="~1.2.1" />
> <plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr" spec="~2.1.4"/>
>
> <plugin name="cordova-plugin-codeplay-share-app-link" source="npm" spec="0.0.3" />
>
> <plugin name="cordova-plugin-safariviewcontroller" source="npm" spec="1.6.0"/>
> <!-- <plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine" source="npm" spec="1.2.1"  /> -->
> <!-- <plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr" source="npm" spec="2.1.4"  /> -->
>
> <plugin name="uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.istablet" source="npm" spec="1.2.0"  />
> <plugin name="cordova-plugin-screen-orientation" source="npm" spec="3.0.2"  />
> <plugin name="uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator" source="npm" spec="5.0.5">
>   <variable name="GOOGLE_API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID" value="" />
> </plugin>
> <plugin name="cordova-plugin-phone-call" source="npm" spec="1.0.7" />
> <plugin name="cordova-plugin-codeplay-share-app-link" source="npm" spec="0.0.3" />
>
>
>
> <edit-config target="NSCameraUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
>     <string>You can take a photo of your asset using camera and upload it into the app</string>
> </edit-config>
> <edit-config target="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
>     <string>You can select photo of your asset in your photo library and upload it into the app</string>
> </edit-config>
> <edit-config target="NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
>     <string>Need photo library access to save pictures there</string>
> </edit-config>
>
>
> <platform name="android">
>     <icon density="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
>     <icon density="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
>     <icon density="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
>     <icon density="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
>     <icon density="xxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
>     <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
>
>       <resource-file src="www/res/icon/android/notification.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable/notification.png" />
>     
>     <splash density="port-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
>     <splash density="port-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
>     <splash density="port-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
>     <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
>     <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
>     <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
> </platform>
> <platform name="ios">
>   <icon height="57" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon.png" width="57" />
>   <icon height="114" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
>   <icon height="40" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" />
>   <icon height="80" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
>   <icon height="50" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" />
>   <icon height="100" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
>   <icon height="60" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" />
>   <icon height="120" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
>   <icon height="180" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
>   <icon height="72" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
>   <icon height="144" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
>   <icon height="76" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" />
>   <icon height="152" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
>   <icon height="29" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" />
>   <icon height="58" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
>   <icon height="87" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
>   <icon height="1024" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-1024.png" width="1024"  />
>   <splash height="1136" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
>   <splash height="1334" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
>   <splash height="2208" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
>   <splash height="2048" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
>   <splash height="1024" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
>   <splash height="960" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
>   <splash height="480" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
>   </platform>  
> <splash src="splash.png" />
> <icon src="icon.png" /> </widget>
> ```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cordova run with ios error .. Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34166175/cordova-run-with-ios-error-error-code-65-for-command-xcodebuild-with-args)