# PhaseScriptExecution when trying to execute ionic cordova run ios

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cocoapods

When I tried to build my application on IOS emulator, it shows the following error, I search online and I found it has something to do with Pod, but I didn't get any useful solutions for this.

```
The following build commands failed:
        PhaseScriptExecution Copy\ www\ directory /Users/kai/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RADAR_Questionnaire-ewiaqvtxwvvffzdyqzeazoxksrcm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/RADAR\ Questionnaire.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RADAR\ Questionnaire.build/Script-304B58A110DAC018002A0835.sh (in target 'RADAR Questionnaire' from project 'RADAR Questionnaire')
(1 failure)
xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65
```

By the way, the app can build fine until I upgrade my mac from 11 (Big surf) -> 12 (Monetary ), I am not sure does it have something to do with the upgrade.

Comment: What have you tried so far? For example, did you try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39327224/796446

Comment: Hi @E.Maggini Yes, I have tried this solution so far, and I also tried to remove some file in the xcode-> build phase, but there's no luck.